# jQuery comparison filter

Tags: jquery, filter

I have two sets of elements with (sometimes) corresponding rel and id attributes:

```
<a rel="1" style="display:none"/>
<a rel="2" style="display:none"/>
<a rel="3" style="display:none"/>
and
<p id="1"/>
<p id="3"/>
<p id="chocolate"/>
```

I want an `<a>` element to appear when a `<p>` with a matching ID is loaded via a `.get()` request.

I figured I'd use filter(), but can't get it to work.  I tried

```
  $('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('rel') == $('p').attr('id'); 
  }).show();
```

This seems to work on the the first element, but my understanding of filter() is that it should go through the whole list.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('p').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == $anchor.attr('rel')) {
            $anchor.show();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm really not sure about the use of `filter` for what you're trying to do, maybe someone else can shed some light on that?

Comment: `filter` will work but he has to check against more than just the first paragraph element.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  I like geowa4's suggestion, but I still need to check to see if there is a matching ID.  I can't guarantee that a loaded element will match the element that I want to show.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`$('p').attr('id')` will only ever return the ID of the first matched element. So your filter function will only ever return true if the anchor has the same `rel` attribute as the first paragraph found by jQuery. So you are right, in that `filter` will go through every anchor, but you aren't going through every paragraph.

When the paragraph is loaded, you know its ID. Therefore, you can just do this:

```
$('a[rel='+paragraphID+']').show();
```